# endless database connection with a thread application

Tags: java, database-connection, ojdbc

i have made a thread application that is checking on some things on the database and make some transactions but the problem i have it is making endless inactive connection then it is causing the database to hang

i have used this code

```
GenericObjectPool connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool(null);
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);
        connectionPool.setMaxActive(10);
        connectionPool.setWhenExhaustedAction((byte) 1);
        connectionPool.setMaxWait(30000);
        connectionPool.setMaxIdle(-1);
        connectionPool.setTestOnBorrow(false);
        connectionPool.setTestOnReturn(false);
        connectionPool.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(-1);
        connectionPool.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(-1);
        connectionPool.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(-1);
        connectionPool.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory,connectionPool,null,null,false,true);
        poolableConnectionFactory.setValidationQuery(null);
        poolableConnectionFactory.setDefaultReadOnly(false);
        poolableConnectionFactory.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
        PoolingDriver driver = new PoolingDriver();
        driver.registerPool("pro",connectionPool);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:pro");
```

any one has an idea?

Note that : i have changed `connectionPool.setMaxIdle(-1);` value to `connectionPool.setMaxIdle(0);` then i started to get exception connection is already closed

Comment: Have you tried to close the connection after the task has been completed? Have you tried to use the same connection for multiple tasks?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes and yes

Comment: Please add the code where thread accesses the connection and closes it